# Python: How to get all the ordered options from lists in

Tags: python, iteration

I have the following method

```
a = [1, 11, 111]
b = [2, 22, 222]
c = [3, 33, 333]
list_of_lists = [a, b, c]
lists_with_the_i_elements = [0 for x in range(len(list_of_lists))]
for i in range(0, len(list_of_lists)):
    lists_with_the_i_elements[i] = [list_i[i] for list_i in list_of_lists]
result = list(itertools.product(lists_with_the_i_elements[0],lists_with_the_i_elements[1],lists_with_the_i_elements[2]))
print(result)
```

reuslt:

```
[(1, 11, 111),
(1, 11, 222), 
(1, 11, 333), 
(1, 22, 111), 
(1, 22, 222), 
(1, 22, 333), 
(1, 33, 111), 
(1, 33, 222), 
(1, 33, 333), 
(2, 11, 111), 
(2, 11, 222), 
(2, 11, 333),
(2, 22, 111), 
(2, 22, 222), 
(2, 22, 333), 
(2, 33, 111), 
(2, 33, 222), 
(2, 33, 333),
(3, 11, 111),
(3, 11, 222),
(3, 11, 333),
(3, 22, 111), 
(3, 22, 222), 
(3, 22, 333), 
(3, 33, 111), 
(3, 33, 222), 
(3, 33, 333)]
```

expected result is:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,22,3]
[1,222,3]
[1,2,33]
[1,22,33]
[1,222,33]
[1,2,333]
[1,22,333]
[1,222,333]
[11,2,3]
[11,22,3]
[11,222,3]
[11,2,33]
[11,22,33]
[11,222,33]
[11,2,333]
[11,22,333]
[11,222,333]
...
```

I want to have a function that when it will receive `list_of_lists` it will return following output:
Hence, I want to have a function that will give me all the listing combinations, which are selections of a member from each list  in the input when the value index is corresponding to the list index in the input.

Another simple example:

```
def combo(*args):
     #do something
...
combo([1],[2],[3])
===>[1,2,3]
combo([1],[2],[3,33])
===>[1,2,3],[1,2,33]
```

I went over all the options in `itertools` and didn't find any solution.

Comment: as well as 12, 112, 113

Comment: I fixed the question, it was wrong...I got confused

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should help you:

```
list(itertools.product([1,11,111], [2, 22, 222], [3, 33, 333]))
```

Comment: uhm.. nope, it's still unclear. An example maybe? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I went over itertools and random googling - I can just implement my self, but I look for the 'pythonic' way for it

Comment: the 'python' way of doing it is just using the standard library. Just tell me why the `itertools.product` doesn't serve your purposes